# Sylius: error after composer update on sylius 0.17

Tags: sylius

i have installed Sylius as following:

```
$ composer create-project sylius/sylius
$ cd sylius
$ php app/console sylius:install
```

Installed versions: Symfony 2.7.7 and Sylius 0.17

All things were working fine until i did composer update. Here was Symfony updated to 2.8.4-dev. I have changed nothing in composer.json. Now i become an error on startpage if i call app_dev.php

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Doctrine is not available.") in SyliusWebBundle:Frontend:layout.html.twig at line 97.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
1 linked Exception:

```
RuntimeException »
```

Debug-Info: CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Doctrine is not available.") in "SyliusWebBundle:Frontend:layout.html.twig" at line 97." at /.../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Template.php line 182

How can i keep the versionnumber of Symfony and Sylius on composer update?

**Update 05.Apr 2016:**

Result of composer show -i sylius/sylius:

```
name     : sylius/sylius
descrip. : E-Commerce platform for PHP, based on Symfony framework.
keywords : 
versions : * v0.17.0
type     : project
license  : MIT License (MIT) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html#licenseText
source   : [git] https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius.git 73397b078f2b34982040b4bcfc8b79532262966d
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/Sylius/Sylius/zipball/73397b078f2b34982040b4bcfc8b79532262966d 73397b078f2b34982040b4bcfc8b79532262966d
names    : sylius/sylius, sylius/addressing, sylius/addressing-bundle, sylius/admin-bundle, sylius/api-bundle, sylius/archetype, sylius/archetype-bundle, sylius/attribute, sylius/attribute-bundle, sylius/cart, sylius/cart-bundle, sylius/contact, sylius/contact-bundle, sylius/content-bundle, sylius/core, sylius/core-bundle, sylius/currency, sylius/currency-bundle, sylius/fixtures-bundle, sylius/flow-bundle, sylius/installer-bundle, sylius/inventory, sylius/inventory-bundle, sylius/locale, sylius/locale-bundle, sylius/money-bundle, sylius/order, sylius/order-bundle, sylius/payment, sylius/payment-bundle, sylius/payum-bundle, sylius/pricing, sylius/pricing-bundle, sylius/product, sylius/product-bundle, sylius/promotion, sylius/promotion-bundle, sylius/rbac, sylius/rbac-bundle, sylius/registry, sylius/report, sylius/report-bundle, sylius/resource, sylius/resource-bundle, sylius/search-bundle, sylius/sequence, sylius/sequence-bundle, sylius/settings-bundle, sylius/shipping, sylius/shipping-bundle, sylius/storage, sylius/taxation, sylius/taxation-bundle, sylius/taxonomy, sylius/taxonomy-bundle, sylius/theme-bundle, sylius/translation, sylius/translation-bundle, sylius/ui-bundle, sylius/user, sylius/user-bundle, sylius/variation, sylius/variation-bundle, sylius/web-bundle

autoload
psr-0
Sylius\ => src/

requires
a2lix/translation-form-bundle ~2.0
doctrine/collections ~1.2
doctrine/common ~2.5
doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.3
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle ~1.0
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ~2.2
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ~1.0
doctrine/orm ^2.4.8,<2.5
doctrine/phpcr-odm ^1.3
ext-exif *
ext-fileinfo *
ext-gd *
friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle ^3.0.2
friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle ~1.4
friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle ~1.5
fzaninotto/faker ~1.2
hwi/oauth-bundle ~0.3
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler ~2.0
jackalope/jackalope ^1.1.4
jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal ^1.1.2
jms/serializer-bundle ^0.13|^1.0
jms/translation-bundle ~1.1
knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle ~0.1
knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~1.1
knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle ~1.2
liip/imagine-bundle ~1.0
ocramius/proxy-manager ^1.0
omnipay/omnipay ~2.3
payum/omnipay-bridge ~1.0
payum/payum ~1.0
payum/payum-bundle ~1.0
php ^5.5.9|^7.0
sensio/distribution-bundle ~3.0
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle ~1.1
swiftmailer/swiftmailer ~5.0
symfony-cmf/block-bundle ~1.2
symfony-cmf/content-bundle ~1.2
symfony-cmf/create-bundle ~1.2
symfony-cmf/media-bundle ~1.2
symfony-cmf/menu-bundle ~1.2
symfony-cmf/routing-bundle ^1.4.0-RC1
symfony/assetic-bundle ^2.6
symfony/event-dispatcher ^2.7
symfony/expression-language ^2.7
symfony/form ^2.7
symfony/framework-bundle ^2.7
symfony/intl ^2.7
symfony/monolog-bundle ^2.7
symfony/options-resolver ^2.7
symfony/polyfill-iconv ~1.0
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu ~1.0
symfony/polyfill-mbstring ~1.0
symfony/property-access ^2.7
symfony/proxy-manager-bridge ^2.7
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ^2.3
symfony/symfony ^2.7.7
symfony/twig-bundle ^2.7
twig/extensions ~1.0
twig/twig ~1.11
white-october/pagerfanta-bundle ~1.0
willdurand/hateoas-bundle ^0.4|^1.0
winzou/state-machine-bundle ~0.2
zendframework/zend-hydrator ^1.0|^2.0
zendframework/zend-stdlib ^2.0|^3.0

requires (dev)
akeneo/phpspec-skip-example-extension ~1.2
behat/behat ~3.0
behat/mink ~1.6
behat/mink-browserkit-driver ~1.2
behat/mink-extension ~2.0
behat/mink-selenium2-driver ~1.2
behat/symfony2-extension ~2.0
bossa/phpspec2-expect ^1.0
coduo/php-matcher ^2.1@dev
fabpot/php-cs-fixer ^1.11
lakion/api-test-case ^1.0@dev
lakion/mink-debug-extension ^1.0.3
malukenho/kawaii-gherkin ^0.1.2
matthiasnoback/symfony-config-test ^1.4
matthiasnoback/symfony-dependency-injection-test ^0.7.6
phpspec/phpspec ^2.4
phpunit/phpunit ~4.1
se/selenium-server-standalone ^2.52

suggests
ext-iconv For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component
ext-intl For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component
ext-mbstring For better performance than using Symfony Polyfill Component

replaces
sylius/addressing self.version
sylius/addressing-bundle self.version
sylius/admin-bundle self.version
sylius/api-bundle self.version
sylius/archetype self.version
sylius/archetype-bundle self.version
sylius/attribute self.version
sylius/attribute-bundle self.version
sylius/cart self.version
sylius/cart-bundle self.version
sylius/contact self.version
sylius/contact-bundle self.version
sylius/content-bundle self.version
sylius/core self.version
sylius/core-bundle self.version
sylius/currency self.version
sylius/currency-bundle self.version
sylius/fixtures-bundle self.version
sylius/flow-bundle self.version
sylius/installer-bundle self.version
sylius/inventory self.version
sylius/inventory-bundle self.version
sylius/locale self.version
sylius/locale-bundle self.version
sylius/money-bundle self.version
sylius/order self.version
sylius/order-bundle self.version
sylius/payment self.version
sylius/payment-bundle self.version
sylius/payum-bundle self.version
sylius/pricing self.version
sylius/pricing-bundle self.version
sylius/product self.version
sylius/product-bundle self.version
sylius/promotion self.version
sylius/promotion-bundle self.version
sylius/rbac self.version
sylius/rbac-bundle self.version
sylius/registry self.version
sylius/report self.version
sylius/report-bundle self.version
sylius/resource self.version
sylius/resource-bundle self.version
sylius/search-bundle self.version
sylius/sequence self.version
sylius/sequence-bundle self.version
sylius/settings-bundle self.version
sylius/shipping self.version
sylius/shipping-bundle self.version
sylius/storage self.version
sylius/taxation self.version
sylius/taxation-bundle self.version
sylius/taxonomy self.version
sylius/taxonomy-bundle self.version
sylius/theme-bundle self.version
sylius/translation self.version
sylius/translation-bundle self.version
sylius/ui-bundle self.version
sylius/user self.version
sylius/user-bundle self.version
sylius/variation self.version
sylius/variation-bundle self.version
sylius/web-bundle self.version
```

Comment: Since you did `composer update`, what version of Sylius are you using now? Could you paste the results of `composer show -i sylius/sylius` ?

Comment: This error is the result of Doctrine PHPCR not being available for some reason

Comment: ..by not available I mean, the service for Doctrine PHPCR is not registered and there is not injected into the Symfony CMF helper for Twig.

Comment: Do you have any tipp, how i can prevent this problem?

Comment: A temporary fix is to open `src/Sylius/Bundle/WebBundle/Resources/Frontend/layout.html.twig` and remove `{% block slideshow_sidebar %}{% endblock %}` and the next ~16 lines up to but not including `{% endblock %}`. In the long term, I'll need to check if this requires a bug fix

Comment: that helps. thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thought, after reviewing the last commit to symfony-cmf/core-bundle

https://github.com/symfony-cmf/core-bundle/commit/d47ac0f193139a90ecece20c46f42e588213824e

a better fix is to just add the following to your main config.yml :

```
cmf_core:
    persistence:
        phpcr:
            enabled: true
```

This will allow the setter function to inject the ManagerRegistry service in Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\CmfCoreExtension

<strike>I believe the cause of this Exception is that the Doctrine\Bundle\PHPCRBundle\ManagerRegistry service is not being injected into the Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\CmfHelper constructor.</strike>

Try adding `<argument type="service" id="doctrine_phpcr" on-invalid="ignore"/>` to the the symfony-cmf dependency injection service configuration file
`symfony-cmf/core-bundle/Resources/config/services.xml`
as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="cmf_core.persistence.phpcr.manager_name">null</parameter>
        <parameter key="cmf_core.twig_extension.class">Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\Twig\Extension\CmfExtension</parameter>
        <parameter key="cmf_core.templating.helper.class">Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\Templating\Helper\CmfHelper</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>

        <service id="cmf_core.twig.children_extension" class="%cmf_core.twig_extension.class%" public="false">
            <argument type="service" id="cmf_core.templating.helper"/>
            <tag name="twig.extension"/>
        </service>

        <service id="cmf_core.templating.helper" class="%cmf_core.templating.helper.class%" public="false">
            <argument type="service" id="cmf_core.publish_workflow.checker" on-invalid="ignore"/>
            <argument type="service" id="doctrine_phpcr" on-invalid="ignore"/>
            <tag name="templating.helper" alias="cmf"/>
        </service>

    </services>
</container>
```

Comment: The update in config.yml was the solution. Thankyou very much!